# How to prevent content showing up under overlapping elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a hero image that has an overlapping box and I'm trying to add content outside of the box. However when I try to add any content below the overlapping box the content shows up behind the box instead of below. How can I make the content show below the box with responsiveness in mind?

```css
.shell {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}


/* overlap */

.shell:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/x866XdV/test-hero.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.shell-header {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.shell-body {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #FFF;
  max-width: 85%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
  <div class="shell">
    <div class="shell-header"></div>
    <div class="shell-body">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a `.wrapper` for everything that falls after `.shell` and add `padding-top` to the `.wrapper`.

```css
section {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.shell {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}


/* overlap */

.shell:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/x866XdV/test-hero.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.shell-header {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.shell-body {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #FFF;
  max-width: 85%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-top: 9rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .wrapper {
    padding-top: 6rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .wrapper {
    padding-top: 11rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="shell">
    <div class="shell-header"></div>
    <div class="shell-body">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: When I pulled up Chrome's inspect mode to check how it'd look on certain phones some of the content will still appear underneath the box.

Comment: @canijusttravel Then you just need to add another media query that handles these resolutions. I noticed the Samsung galaxy s8+ & the galaxy fold were the two that were troublesome. I added an additional query to handle these screens. See edits.